# Can backgroundColor overlap a div?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I created an animation which highlights active elements. Now my challenge is that I want that
highlighting/backgroundColor to overlap a bit without adding padding to the element itself. Currently, the
background is too close to the element (svg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lIwW.jpg

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {},
  highlight: {
    animation: `$yellowflash-bg 4s ease-in-out`,
  },
  "@keyframes yellowflash-bg": {
    from: {
      backgroundColor: "yellow",
    },
    to: {
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
    },
  },
}));

const Element = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]:
          currentElementRef &&
          currentElementRef === elementRefs.map.get(element.id),
      })}
    >
      <ElementType
        [...]
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What do you really mean by 'the background is too close to the element'? Have you considered negative margins and rgba() color values?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear enough. I meant that the yellow background is "touching" the element. However, I want the background to big around 10px around the svg / div element.

Comment: My gut feeling tells me that you should wrap the element within another <div>.

Comment: Maybe add something like ´div {transform: scale(1.1);}´

Comment: I tried that and increases the div, but unfortunately also the div's inside that div. scale(1.0) for the child div doesn't change that behaviour. (Reference https://imgur.com/a/uMBY29J )